# How can I get the result from R program with Python?

Tags: python, r, windows, subprocess

I have the R program which result I want to get with Python. First, I have tried this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call ("C:\py\test.R", shell=True)
```

But this program returns 1, and it is not that I`d like to get. Also I tried to install rpy2, but I had error with its installing.
Then I tried this:

```
import subprocess 
command = ("C:\R400\bin\Rscript.exe " "--vanilla C:\py\test.R") 
subprocess.Popen(command)
variable_name = subprocess.check_output(command)
print(variable_name)
```

But this code (Jupyter Notebook and IDLE Python 3.8 64 bit on Windows 10) gets an error:

FileNotFoundError

What could be the reason? How can I fix it? How can I run a R program with Python, but without using rpy2?

Also I tried with cmd. I create a file run.py in the folder with test.R:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['Rscript', 'test.R'], shell=False)
```

But where was nothing when I tried `python3 run.py` with cmd. 
Also I failed with `python3 run.py > testout.txt` when I tried to write the result down in the special textual file.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "results to get with python"? Your code above is only running the R process? Does your process produces any sort of outputs? Do you want those outputs read into python?

Comment: This R code is for the calculating the difference between matrices and I`d like to read the outputs with Python

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What what kind of format is the R process producing? Is it a dataframe? Value, array? Etc, and is it being written to a file? If so, why not just read the file into python? Running the R script alone won’t automatically ready the output, you need to read the file into python after the subprocess is finished.